# Cardboard Magnet Detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got some trouble with my unity cardboard app. May some of you guys can help me.
I have build a little Island with Animations and A second island as a main menu.
So when the apps starts, you see the Island from above and the Logo of the App.
When the user pull down the magnet button on side the app will starts another level.

I used this scripts:

http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Unity_-_Detecting_Google_Cardboard_Click

Detecting Google Cardboard Magnetic Button Click - Singleton Implementation
CardboardMagnetSensor.cs and CardboardTriggerControlMono.cs

I created a script in my asset folder(CardboardMagnetSensor.cs) like in the description from Link. Than I created a second script(CardboardTriggerControlMono.cs) like in the discription an dragged it onto my CardboardMain in may Projekt.

The CardboardTriggerControlMono.cs looks like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CardboardTriggerControlMono : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool magnetDetectionEnabled = true;

    void Start() {
        CardboardMagnetSensor.SetEnabled(magnetDetectionEnabled);
        // Disable screen dimming:
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;


    } 

    void Update () {
        if (!magnetDetectionEnabled) return;
        if (CardboardMagnetSensor.CheckIfWasClicked()) {
            Debug.Log("Cardboard trigger was just clicked");
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
            CardboardMagnetSensor.ResetClick();

        }
    }
}
```

The CarboardMagnetSensor:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CardboardMagnetSensor {
    // Constants:
    private const int WINDOW_SIZE = 40;
    private const int NUM_SEGMENTS = 2;
    private const int SEGMENT_SIZE = WINDOW_SIZE / NUM_SEGMENTS;
    private const int T1 = 30, T2 = 130;

    // Variables:
    private static bool wasClicked;           // Flips to true once set off.
    private static bool sensorEnabled;        // Is sensor active.
    private static List<Vector3> sensorData;  // Keeps magnetic sensor data.
    private static float[] offsets;           // Offsets used to detect click.


    // Call this once at beginning to enable detection.
    public static void SetEnabled(bool enabled) {
        Reset();
        sensorEnabled = enabled;
        Input.compass.enabled = sensorEnabled;

    }

    // Reset variables.
    public static void Reset() {
        sensorData = new List<Vector3>(WINDOW_SIZE);
        offsets = new float[SEGMENT_SIZE];
        wasClicked = false;
        sensorEnabled = false;

    }

    // Poll this once every frame to detect when the magnet button was clicked
    // and if it was clicked make sure to call "ResetClick()"
    // after you've dealt with the action, or it will continue to return true.
    public static bool CheckIfWasClicked() {
        UpdateData();
        return wasClicked;
    }

    // Call this after you've dealt with a click operation.
    public static void ResetClick() {
        wasClicked = false;
    }

    // Updates 'sensorData' and determines if magnet was clicked.
    private static void UpdateData() {
        Vector3 currentVector = Input.compass.rawVector;



        if (currentVector.x == 0 && currentVector.y == 0 && currentVector.z == 0) {

            return;
        }

        if(sensorData.Count >= WINDOW_SIZE) sensorData.RemoveAt(0);
        sensorData.Add(currentVector);

        // Evaluate model:
        if(sensorData.Count < WINDOW_SIZE) return;

        float[] means = new float[2];
        float[] maximums = new float[2];
        float[] minimums = new float[2];

        Vector3 baseline = sensorData[sensorData.Count - 1];

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS; i++) {
            int segmentStart = 20 * i;
            offsets = ComputeOffsets(segmentStart, baseline);

            means[i] = ComputeMean(offsets);
            maximums[i] = ComputeMaximum(offsets);
            minimums[i] = ComputeMinimum(offsets);
        }

        float min1 = minimums[0];
        float max2 = maximums[1];

        // Determine if button was clicked.
        if(min1 < T1 && max2 > T2) {
            sensorData.Clear();
            wasClicked = true;  // Set button clicked to true.
            // NOTE: 'wasClicked' will now remain true until "ResetClick()" is called.
        }
    }

    private static float[] ComputeOffsets(int start, Vector3 baseline) {
        for(int i = 0; i < SEGMENT_SIZE; i++) {
            Vector3 point = sensorData[start + i];
            Vector3 o = new Vector3(point.x - baseline.x, point.y - baseline.y, point.z - baseline.z);
            offsets[i] = o.magnitude;
        }
        return offsets;
    }

    private static float ComputeMean(float[] offsets) {
        float sum = 0;
        foreach(float o in offsets) {
            sum += o;
        }
        return sum / offsets.Length;
    }

    private static float ComputeMaximum(float[] offsets) {
        float max = float.MinValue;
        foreach(float o in offsets) {
            max = Mathf.Max(o, max);
        }
        return max;
    }

    private static float ComputeMinimum(float[] offsets) {
        float min = float.MaxValue;
        foreach(float o in offsets) {
            min = Mathf.Min(o, min);
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

And my steps:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3887/mtjygjan_jpg.htm

(sorry I´m not able to upload pictures here)

How ever, it wont work. When I start the app and pull down the magnet, nothing happens. May I did something wrong with switching the level over level index?

I use a nexus 4 and 5 for testing the app

Thanks allot and greetz to you!

Phillip

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Google Cardboard SDK for Unity, it currently has a bug that prevents Unity from seeing the magnet (and gyro, and accelerometer).  That is probably why your script is not working.  Until the bug is fixed, there is no good workaround, but you can instead use the property Cardboard.CardboardTriggered to detect if the magnet was pulled.

Update for Unity 5:  The sensor bug is gone.  Cardboard SDK does not block the sensors.